# Go to an Activity After Opening Push Notification

Tags: java, android, android-push-notification

The following code serves as my handler when the user taps a push notification. The code is working properly and `launchURL` is accurately recorded in my log. However, as a next step I would like to direct the user to an activity called `ViewPushLink`. I have attempted to follow similar instructions found elsewhere on S.O., but as a newbie, I would appreciate some specific help.

```
class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
     public static String launchURL;

    @Override
    public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
        OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
        JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;

        if (data != null) {
            launchURL = data.optString("launchURL");
            if (launchURL != null) {
                Log.i("OneSignalExample", "launchURL value: " + launchURL);

            }
        }

        }

}
```

EDIT: `ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler` is called from my Main Activity as show below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


       private ProgressDialog progress;

    public static boolean isNetworkStatusAvailable (Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivityManager != null)
        {
            NetworkInfo netInfos = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if(netInfos != null)
                if(netInfos.isConnected())
                    return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        } else setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        // OneSignal Initialization
        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler())
                .init();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41863680/onesignal-android-notificationopenedhandler-start-activity check this out.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Activity to this; Surely it will help you.

```
class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
     public static String launchURL;

    @Override
    public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
        OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
        JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;

        if (data != null) {
            launchURL = data.optString("launchURL");
            if (launchURL != null) {
                Log.i("OneSignalExample", "launchURL value: " + launchURL);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext, ViewPushLink.class)
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        }

}
```

Comment: I'm receiving the following error in Android Studio: `cannot resolve symbol getApplicationContext.` Also, `cannot resolve method startActivity.` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I should note that `ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler` is a separate class (not nested under any classes).

Comment: from which class you are calling this activity?

Comment: It is called from `onCreate` under `MainActivity`. See my edited answer for the code.

Comment: Let your class extend `AppCompatActivity` then the errors should be resolved

Comment: check this out.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41863680/onesignal-android-notificationopenedhandler-start-activity
surely it will help

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in the Application Class of your project.
 For push notification handling using the OneSignal SDK, three things need to be considered.{if your project has multiple fragments and one Main Activity(Navigation Drawer Activity) and rest of other activities get called from the fragments of MainActivity}

1. Target Activity
2. Related Actions like, which part of your
   activity, which fragment you want to open, differentiate which each
   with some action that you can find in the jsonObject Data
3. Intent
   Flags, an example you want to open an Activity, whose instance is
   already in backStack, so you may want to clear the back stack and
   open the new instance of the activity or may open the same instance.

Example:

```
public XYZApplication extends Application{

class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
 public static String launchURL;
@Override
public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
    OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
    JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;

        if (data != null) {
            String target = data.optString("target");
            String action = "";
            switch (target) {
                case "xyz":
                    action = data.optString("action");
                    Utils.setTarget(target);
                    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("xyz")
                            || action.equalsIgnoreCase("abc")) {
                        Intent xyzIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), XYZActivity.class);
                        homeIntent.putExtra("action_key", "action_xyz");
                        homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(xyzIntent);
}
```

for more details refer to one signal SDK Documentation
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs

Comment: Put OneSignal init call in Application Class.